Is a back_insert_iterator valid for the lifetime of the container?
I think I know the answer to this, but I'd appreciate a sanity check.
Does iterator invalidation apply to std::back_insert_iterators?
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto v = std::vector<int>{ 0, 1, 2 };
    auto iter = std::back_inserter(v);
    *iter++ = 3;
    v.clear();    // invalidates iterators, but
    *iter++ = 4;  //  back_insert_iterator is special?
    assert(v.size() == 1 && v[0] == 4);
    return 0;
}

This code works for me because the std::back_insert_iterator implementation from my vendor doesn't hold an iterator (or pointer or reference).  It simply calls the container's push_back method.
But does the standard require that implementation?  Could another vendor's back_insert_iterator hold and maintain a one-past-the-end iterator to use with a call to the container's insert method?  It seems that would meet the requirements.  This difference, of course, is that it would be vulnerable to invalidation.

I know cppreference.com is not authoritative, but it's more accessible than the standard.

[A vector's clear method] [i]nvalidates any ... iterators referring to contained elements. Any past-the-end iterators are also invalidated. [cppreference.com, emphasis added]

A std::back_insert_iterator could be the poster child of a past-the-end iterator.

the back inserter iterator does not refer to any elements in the vector, it just refers to the vector.  * calls push_back and ++ is a non-op: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator

@NathanOliver: it is = which calls push_back, * is no-op too.

@Jarod42 Aha, yeah, * is for regular input iterators.

"A std::back_insert_iterator could be the poster child of a past-the-end iterator." -- Not according to cppreference's std::end page (emphasis added): "Returns c.end(), which is typically an iterator one past the end of the sequence represented by c." The phrase uses "end" as a person probably would before learning iterators; it views "end" as the last element, rather than as the result of calling end(). The phrase would be more accurate as "past-the-end-element", but that phrasing is not popular.

Could another vendor's back_insert_iterator hold and maintain a one-past-the-end iterator to use with a call to the container's insert method? It seems that would meet the requirements. - How would that work if back_inserter were called twice in a row? In this regards, std::inserter is more interesting - you do pass an iterator to it.

@Evg:  The pattern is *it++ = value;.  The simple implementation treats the increment as a no-op.  An implementation that "holds and maintains" an iterator would actually do the increment.

Per [back.insert.iterator]
namespace std {
  template<class Container>
  class back_insert_iterator {
  protected:
    Container* container;

  public:
    using iterator_category = output_iterator_tag;
    using value_type        = void;
    using difference_type   = ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer           = void;
    using reference         = void;
    using container_type    = Container;

    constexpr explicit back_insert_iterator(Container& x);
    constexpr back_insert_iterator& operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value);
    constexpr back_insert_iterator& operator=(typename Container::value_type&& value);

    constexpr back_insert_iterator& operator*();
    constexpr back_insert_iterator& operator++();
    constexpr back_insert_iterator  operator++(int);
  };
}


constexpr explicit back_insert_iterator(Container& x);
1 Effects: Initializes container with addressof(x).
constexpr back_insert_iterator& operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value);
2 Effects: As if by: container->push_back(value);
3 Returns: *this.
constexpr back_insert_iterator& operator=(typename Container::value_type&& value);
4 Effects: As if by: container->push_back(std​::​move(value));
5 Returns: *this.
[...]

As we can see the iterator gets a pointer to the container and then push_back is called directly on the container, so no chance of UB.
